# Как подгрузить соответствующую картинку с другой страницы

Tags: jquery, get

Нужно в корзине товаров, добавить фото товарам у которых фото отсутствуют, с соответствующих страниц товаров, по своей ссылке для каждого товара.

**Корзина**

```
<div id="order-table">
  <div>
    <div>1.</div>
    <div>
      <a href="" class="ulightbox"><img src=""></a>
    </div>
    <div><a href="ссылка-на-страницу-с-картинкой-1">Название товара 1</a></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <hr>
    <div>2.</div>
    <div>
      <a href="/ссылка-на-картинку-есть.jpg" class="ulightbox"><img src="/ссылка-на-картинку-есть.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div><a href="/ссылка-на-страницу-с-картинкой-2">Название товара 2</a></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <hr>
    <div>3.</div>
    <div>
      <a href="" class="ulightbox"><img src=""></a>
    </div>
    <div><a href="/ссылка-на-страницу-с-картинкой-3">Название товара 3</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Если ссылка на картинку есть ничего не делаем. Если нет, то на странице с картинкой находим блок с картинкой по `class="link-photo"`, копируем `src` и вставляем в соответствующую товару конструкцию `<a href=""><img src=""></a>` в `href=""` и `src=""`

```
<img alt="Название товара 1" src="https://ссылка-на-фото-название-1.jpg" class="link-photo">
<img alt="Название товара 2" src="https://ссылка-на-фото-название-2.jpg" class="link-photo">
<img alt="Название товара 3" src="https://ссылка-на-фото-название-3.jpg" class="link-photo">
```

Если картинки `class="link-photo"` на странице с товаром нет, копируем `div class="shop-item-foto"` и заменяем

```
<a href=""><img src=""></a>
```

на скопированное

```
<div class="shop-item-foto"></div>
```

Comment: Нет, относительной не будет!

Comment: jquery работает с текущим домом, а если будет делать для каждого запрос, он вам сервер положит. Вы уверены что такое нужно? Проще подложить картинку css и ее перекроет если есть другая.

Comment: Ruslan, там надо то 1 максимум 5 запросов, я думаю сервер выдержит :)

Comment: Как бы-то ни было, но тянуть в нагрузку еще пять страниц это не по взрослому. А страницы динамически создаются? Если да, тогда лучше и ссылки на картинки сразу же создавать используя тот же код, что используется для из генерации на запрашиваемых страницах с товарами. Даже если из-за этого придется переделывать что-то, оно того стоит.